# Incorrect display of objects in solid view

Tags: artifacts

My objects located close to each other and when they are displaying partially. They also disappear sometimes then zoom in/zoom out. [image]

There are two plains above another plane on the image.

Comment: This is called Z-fighting. Your objects seem to be particularly close to another plane beneath them. Are these two objects on the plane? As in, do they share the same space as the plane? Or are they above it? And do you need them to stay in that position.

Comment: This is a usual behavior when two or more faces are exactly overlapping: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting. Since there is no way for the openGL renderer to choose what plane to display, it displays a little bit of both. You should slightly move the small planes above the large plane to fix this.

Comment: It is interesting what in the orthographic view there is no such problem. This planes is slightly above main plane.

Comment: One thing that helped me before was that I had to change the clipping of the viewport camera to see objects close together without Z-fighting. Try to make the clip start of the viewport camera located in the menu, (after pressing "N" on your keyboard) set to a value of 1 or higher. This may help.

Comment: Increasing clipping start point helped) You can make an answer)